# Using multiple likes in statement VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check if the first digit in a cell is not 7 or 8, then a message  should pop up on the screen. 
The issue with my code is that it checks only the first line and disregards the other :

```
Dim bCell As Range
Set bCell = Range("B13")
If Not bCell Like "8*" _
Or bCell Like "7*" Then

MsgBox
```

Comment: `Or Not bCell Like "7*"`

Comment: Thanks but now it doesn't even recognize the first "Like"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Not` only applies to the first condition (checking for an 8), because it's a lower precedence than the `Or` operator. One solution is to add a second `Not` for the second condition (checking for a 7), as Scott Crane suggests.

Alternately, you could include parentheses around the whole condition, like

```
If Not (bCell Like "8*" _
Or bCell Like "7*") Then
```

For more info on operator precendence, see the "Note" section [here on Microsoft Docs for VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/not-operator#remarks).

> **Note:**
>   Since the logical and bitwise operators have a lower precedence than other arithmetic and relational operators, any bitwise operations should be enclosed in parentheses to ensure accurate execution.

Comment: Thanks so much, Franklin! The parantheses made it possible!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Not bCell Like`, why not use `Left()`?

```
If Left(bCell,1) <> 7 and Left(bCell,1) <> 8 Then ...
```

Otherwise,

```
If Not bCell Like "8*" And Not bCell Like "7*" Then
```

**Note**: You need to use `And`, not `Or`. If you use `Or`, it's going to do the msgbox (or whatever code), no matter what is in the cell.